Should Escape key close non modal dialogs?
w3.org's example for modal dialogs include Escape as a keyboard shortcut for closing the modal dialog. Chromium browsers closes <dialog> elements, if they were opened using showModal(), but not show(). Are these examples likely to be well researched or is just an accident?
Is there any guidance on the Escape key in relation to non modal dialogs in web applications?

You can't use Escape to close non-modal dialogs. This is because they don't interfere between the user and the main content. To close a non-modal dialog, you need to use a tab to select the close button and treat it as any other component in the layout, like the recommendations in StackExchange.
It is a non-modal dialog since it does not implement a pop-over on the screen. You can continue browsing even with the alert on the screen.

This article can help you learn how to treat each component.
Modal & Non-Modal Dialog

Also, you need to keep track of the focus tag programmatically. When you open a non-modal window, you have many elements from the DOM, which makes it difficult for users with reading technologies to keep track of the selected element.

You could have non modal dialogs that do interfere with the content, by for example overlaying a part it. The article mentions the compose window/dialog in Gmail, which is closable with Escape.

That could be one of the reasons they changed the look and feel of writing an email for a modal dialog.

The expanded editor is modal yes, but not the minimal one in the bottom right corner that you get directly after clicking compose. Both can be closed with Escape.

The article doesn't deal with Esc at all, and from an accessibility POV I would not take advice from NNg.
Anyway, It is always a good idea to stick to standard practices. Using Esc to dismiss any dialog, be they modal or non-modal, is completely acceptable. Example: The dropdowns on StackExchange can be dismissed using Esc.
The only reason to NOT use Esc would be, if you want to prevent the user from committing a serious error (personal data, financial ruin or bodily harm), by forcing them to decide on an action, like saving a text before a system crashes
